# Quasi-isometry classes of elementary amenable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry

Is there any elementary argument showing that there exist uncountably many distinct quasi-isometry classes of elementary amenable groups? How about solvable groups?

For amenable groups it follows from the result of Grigorchuk (proved in the 80's) stating that there are uncountably many groups of intermediate growth with pairwise incomparable growth functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The affirmative answer in given by Yves de Cornulier and Romain Tessera in  arXiv:1203.4696.

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't it follows from our paper on lacunary hyperbolic groups? The elementary amenable lacunary hyperbolic groups corresponding to sufficiently different sequences of parameters will be not quasi-isometric because their asymptotic cones corresponding to certain sequences of parameters will not be bi-Lipschitz equivalent (one cone will be a tree while another one won't).

Comment: @Denis: You are too young to be forgetting your own
theorems. :)

Comment: @Mark: I think it does not follow directly, although one can probably prove it this way. One problem is that there  exist 2 elementary amenable groups G, H as in our paper (corresponding to different parameters) such that for any scaling sequence and any ultrafilter, the corresponding cone of at least one of G, H is an R-tree. So any third group cannot be distinguished from both G and H by means of asymptotic cones. It is not obvious to me how to choose those "sufficiently different sequences of parameters" to avoid this problem. 

Comment: @Denis: It does  not seem to be difficult: each group should have a sequence of relations of certain fast growing lengths while in all other groups this sequence misses all relations. I think it is easy. A solvable example is more difficult. One would have to deal with Abels' group or Kharlampovich's group and its factor-groups over central subgroups. Perhaps again asymptotic cones can help. But it is not clear.

Comment: @Mark: Of course, each our group has a sequence of relations of certain fast growing lengths. But we do not know anything about the geometric shape of these relations in the Cayley graph, so it is not clear how to show that the corresponding asymptotic cone is _not_ an R-tree. If we could do this, we could probably also decide whether or not all cones of our groups have cut points (which is an open problem in our paper). 

Comment: @Denis: to any f.g. group $G$, you can associate the set $N(G)$ of ultrafilters $\omega$ such that $Cone(G,\omega,(1/n))$ is a real tree. So $N(G)$ is a QI-invariant of $G$. I think the idea is to show that elementary amenable groups achieve continuum many sets $N(G)$. It's not obvious (and I haven't checked) but I guess you can do this.

Comment: @Denis: I think you are make the problem too complicated. The problem whether all cones have cut points is much more difficult. One does not need to consider all cones. Only those that are guaranteed to be trees and those that are guaranteed to be non-trees. @Yves: What about solvable groups?

Comment: @Yves: Yes, this is the way to go. But the problem is that we know how to prove that some ultrafilters belong to N(G), but we do not know how to prove that an ultrafilter is not in N(G). At least this is not immediate from our paper.

Comment: @Mark: Right, but as I said, it is not clear to me how to prove that a particular cone is not an R-tree.

Comment: @Denis: If a group is infinitely presented one of the cones has non-trivial fundamental group. The non-trivial loop comes from a sequence of defining relations. In our group, we know the lengths of defining relations. That gives scaling constants for a non-tree cone. In another group the same scaling sequence will get a tree. 

Comment: @Mark: Yes, I understand this. So we have 2 non-q.i. groups. In a similar way we can construct infinitely many. But how do we pass to continuously many? 

Comment: @Denis: Create enough sequences in advance, then create groups. It is similar to the fact that there are uncountably many q.i. classes of Thomas-Velickovic groups (I think it also has not been mentioned in their paper or elsewhere). 

Comment: @Mark: In my graduate course on geometric group theory, I usually show that there are T-V groups $G_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha < 2^{\omega}$ such that for every subset $S \subseteq 2^{\omega}$, there is an ultrafilter such that the corresponding cone of $G_{\alpha}$ isn't simply connected if $\alpha \in S$ and is an $\mathbb{R}$-tree otherwise. As you have been pointing out, this kind of "strengthening" is an easy exercise.

Comment: @Mark: OK, here is a very particular question. We are given a sequence $(d_n)$. How do we create an elementary amenable group as in our paper with asymptotic cones corresponding to $(d_n)$ not R-trees? (And how do we prove that they are not R-trees?). This is not similar to Thomas-Velicovic, since they do know how to answer this question, while in our construction this is not at all obvious. 


Comment: @Simon: Of course this kind of "strengthening" is an easy exercise for your construction since you have small cancellations there and you can effectively prove that a given cone is not an R-tree. This is not so in our construction: we know that some cones are not R-trees, but it is not obvious which ones. So fixing sequences in advance does not work without some additional arguments. See my comment to Mark.

Comment: @Denis: If we know $c_i$ (the parameters of the construction), we know the lengths of relations of the virtually free groups approximating the amenable group. It is easy to see which of these sequences of relations tend to a non-trivial loop in the asymptotic cone. One does not need small cancelation for that. In fact a sequence gives a non-trivial loop if the relations of that sequence do not follow from smaller relations of the group. That is the Gromov "divisibility" property. It remains to choose $c_i$ in a proper manner which is, I repeat, easy.  

Comment: @Denis: In fact, I would not fix the sequences in advance. I would construct a complete binary tree of sequences at the same time that I was inductively constructing the groups.

Comment: @Denis: If you still do not know how to do it by January 3 when I return to Nashville, we can discuss it then. I do not think we should take more space here. 